# Multiplayer with multiple app ids

Tags: iphone, ipad, game-center, multiplayer, app-id

I am interested in making an iOS game with a 2 player multiplayer aspect. I'd like to use `Game Centre` to send the data, which seems to work well with 1 app. What I would like to have is a paid and free version of the game, with the ability to play multiplayer ***between*** the paid and free versions.

The problem I have is:

**Is it possible to use `Game Centre` to send data between the paid and free versions of the game, even if they have different app ids?**

From what I've seen online, I don't think that it is possible, and I'll most likely have to have my own server to handle the data transfer. Any insight though would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such option in iTunes-connect.

Here is guide to it 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/15_GameCenter/GameCenter.html

Here are two options you should be looking for

**Groups**: allows you to share your leaderboard and achievement data between apps. Apps in a group do not need to be multiplayer compatible.

**Multiplayer Compatibility**: allows you to specify which apps are compatible with a specific app and therefore, allow multiplayer games between the apps. Apps do not need to be on the same platform or in a group to be multiplayer compatible.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to test this, I've just been very busy! This works wonderfully, I can't believe it's that simple. Thanks a ton!